# how to get jsp output in pdf form using coding

Tags: database, jsp, pdf-generation

i need to transform the output of jsp program into pdf file. suggest me some jar file and code to generate the pdf file of jsp output. iam also retrieving some values from database(mysql). 
I have read about jasper but it couldn't help me in any way. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

FlyingSaucer/XHTMLRenderer (https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer) does a good job of HTML > PDF conversion however it does not work by magic: there are a few steps involved.

Assuming you wanted to export an existing JSP via some Link or Button:

- PDF export Button calls a some Controller or Servlet passing all
  params necessary to regenerate the JSP (i.e. as it was originally
  rendered).
- This Action or Servlet has to invoke the JSP (ensuring any required
  model attributes are set) and write the Response to a String (rather 
  than writing to the standard response).
- Pass this String to XHTMLRenderer to generate the PDF.
- Stream the btye [] returned by HTMLRenderer to the client.

I have added a complete end-to-end example here using a simple Servlet. However the principles will be the same with any framework so you should be able to adapt as required.

https://github.com/alanhay/jsp-to-pdf-exporter

Comment: i have tables and images also in my output. second thing is that i want to do it in jsp coding only.

Comment: Tables and Images will be handled by the solution. I have given you the basics: time to do some work yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by 'invoke the JSP'. Please explain.

Comment: You have a JSP. You need HTML so you need then to call your JSP and read the generated HTML. See lines 88-90 https://github.com/alanhay/jsp-to-pdf-exporter/blob/master/jsp-pdf-export/src/main/java/uk/co/certait/pdf/export/TestServlet.java

Comment: @Alan Hay I also want to convert JSP output to HTML. The application uses struts 1.3 action mapping mechanism. But I do not want to do it through some frontend option but in backend somehow. Would it be possible somehow ?