# jsp page print or convert to PDF with all css applied

Tags: java, jquery, css, jsp, itext

I want to convert a portion of my jsp page to pdf. Now I am considering iText for this. Now iText will convert html code to pdf which is fine. But how to fetch my html code with all the stylling applied?

I have my css classes in external css file. I am trying to fetch html code but not getting the css rules applied to elements.

Is there any alternative way?

Comment: This might help : https://code.google.com/archive/p/flying-saucer/

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/parsing-xml-and-xhtml)? (Plenty examples about using CSS there.)

Comment: All the examples have initially html source in a string a variable. How to get that is my question.

Comment: (http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-external-css-while-generating-pdf) . - check this. They are using `htmlSource.toString().getBytes()`. But how do you get that html source code?

Comment: See my answer here which includes link to full example code. If you only want part of the page use something like JSoup to extract the relevant parts. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27619888/1356423

Comment: Will it give me the html data with all styles applied? Because I have external CSS files.