# Converting JSP Page to PDF

Tags: css, jsp, itext

How to apply multiple external css files in itexts using XMLWorkerHelper in JSP ?
Could anyone provide a solution?

Comment: See the answer and linked example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617616/how-to-get-jsp-output-in-pdf-form-using-coding/27619888#27619888

Answer (score 1):

iText can convert HTML to pdf, but its capabilities are limited in following ways:

- only a subset of HTML tags are supported
- only a subset of css appliers are supported
- the input pages have to be static (dynamic content injection is
  generally not supported)

For reference (as well as examples), feel free to consult the iText website.

- http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker-itext5/basic-html-examples
- http://itextpdf.com/blog/itext-7-and-itext-5-roadmaps-differences-updates

Short summary (of second link); iText will release a HTML-2-PDF module along with iText 7, but again, limitations will apply.

Kind regards,
Joris

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that iText after v 2.x requires a commercial licence for closed source projects.

Comment: @Alan *"Might be worth pointing out ..."* - not really. The op already uses itext 5.x (as `XMLWorkerHelper` was not available before), so the answer (referring to itext 5 and itext 7) does not change the licensing situation. It might be worth discussing licensing when question and answer refer to different versions with different licenses.

Comment: @mkl.  *"It might be worth discussing licensing when question and answer refer to different versions with different licenses"*. Not Really: the reference to XMLWorkerHelper was introduced in his edit 3 hours ago i.e. a long time after my comment was posted (at this point iText was not even mentioned). http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42085481/revisions

Comment: @AlanHay Ah, indeed, the used mechanism and, as a consequence, the itext version the OP used became somewhat clear only after the second edit. Looking at those earlier versions of the question, they actually had been candidates for closing --- too broad / unclear what is asked.