# Creating PDF from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I want to create a PDF file from an existing JSP on my server, as a downloadable report of an order on an electrical appliances web aplication, when you click on "create PDF" button. I've spent many hours investigating about this, but i have only found examples where you have to "model" your own PDF file using the iText Api, by adding Paragraphs, fonts, etc... Is there any way i can "capture" the common JSP output, like the one that dispatches a Servlet, and convert that into PDF?

Edit: I have investigated about using iText5/iText7, with no clear results.

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617616/how-to-get-jsp-output-in-pdf-form-using-coding/27619888#27619888 and the complete example linked to in that answer https://github.com/alanhay/jsp-to-pdf-exporter

Comment: JSP first needs to be rendered to HTML by a Java Application Server, then you can convert the HTML to PDF with iText 7 + pdfHTML.

Comment: Be aware that iText versions > 2 require a commercial licence for non OS projects.